# How to change the URL of the title in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, blogs

Is it possible to change the target URL when clicking on the value `title` defined in `_config.yml` ?

To define the context, I have my static HTML website hosted on GitHub, it's a one page website. I have on the same repository the Jekyll blog accessible on *mysite.github.com/blog*.
When I click on the header title, the Jekyll blog redirect me to */* which is my website and I would like to be redirected in */blog*.

What is the simpliest method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewrite the `header.html` of the `minima` theme template. The goal is to change the target of the link in the header.
To do that :

1. Create a folder `_includes` and a file `header.html` inside
2. Copy and paste the original code for the official repository
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jekyll/minima/master/_includes/header.html into the `header.html` file
3. replace the content of `href="{{ "/" | relative_url }}"` by `href="{{ "/blog" | relative_url }}"`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `url` and `baseurl` in the config for the blog? Baseurl should be used for the "home" page.

Comment: Yes I already try it but it doesn't works because baseurl with the parameter set the adress of blog as mysite.com/blog/blog because of my URL is already /blog...

Comment: What theme are you using? Are you able to edit the navbar component?

Comment: I use `minima` theme and only `jekyll-feed` plugin.